# Appending AJAX loader to menu/nav bar on individual links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using the following theme for our site: http://themes.vivantdesigns.com/vpad/#dashboard.html

I want an ajax loader to show NEXT to the link/tab, when a user clicks a link within the drilldown menu on the left. As you can see from the link, content is dynamically loaded within a:

```
<section id="main-section">Pagename.html loaded here</section>
```

So basically, I want the ajax loader to show to the right of the menu links and disappear when the dynamic content loads. It will be hard to see this pause on the demo link, but heavier database queries will cause it to sit there a moment, and slower connections of course.

Any immediate help is appreciated very much.

I've tried show/hide onClick methods, hiding class on document ready, and nothing seems to work cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of screwing around trying to find where the ajax was happening, I *think* I've worked it out (little familiarity with jQuery/never heard of hashchange or bbq before), so give this a shot.

Assuming you have access to it, the page you referenced is including a JavaScript file called global.js.

Add an initially hidden "loading" image/div/whatever next to each menu item, with an id set similarly to the menu item's name e.g. id="mediaLoading".

Open global.js and head down to line 117:

```
$('#'+id).length && $('#'+id).remove();
```

After this line the ajax call is made, so add the code to show the ajax loader, e.g.

```
var loaderId = h.replace(/^\#/, "") + "Loading";
document.getElementById(loaderId).style.display = 'block'; 
//or $("#" + loaderId).show() or whatever you would use in jQuery
```

Finally, to re-hide it, add similar code into the inline 'complete' function (which would now be around line 127):

```
complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) { 
    document.getElementById(loaderId).style.display = 'none';
}
```

Hope that solves it. It was difficult to test locally.

Keep in mind that since the file's called "global," that obviously might impact a bunch of other pages, so you may want to use null-checks for the loader or a separate file...

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for taking an obviously large amount of time to look into this for me. What are the chances you're online at the moment? I'd like to chat with you about this. I'm having a couple of difficulties and would love to work through it live. Will make it worth your while for sure.

Comment: I'm afraid at the time you posted it was 5am here! I'll be awake and intermittently available over the next 12 hours, though (at some point I'm going to the beach!)

My Skype is "raventhe_"

If I'm not online at the time, send me an offline message with your troubles and I'll diagnose and get back to you asap (assuming that, if we can't work through it live, anything is better than nothing!)